# Update TextView after animation ends Android

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

I am trying to add animation to my linear layout. Below is my code :-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mylinearlayout"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/offerImage"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/startAnimation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/offerImage"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Start"
                 />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Inside my activity's onCreate method, I do like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    .

    LinearLayout ll_mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
    TextView tv_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button btn_startAnimation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startAnimation);

    tv_data.setText("Before Animation");

    btn_StartAnimation.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move);
                ll_mainLayout.setAnimation(animation);

                ll_mainLayout.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    showData();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });


        }

    });




}

public void showData()
{
    tv_data.setText("After Animation");
}
}
```

I can see the animation happening but after the animation the tv_data textview doesn't change to "After Animation";

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Set the AnimationListener on your Animation object instead:

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {
        showData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart (Animation animation) {}
});
```

Also, use `startAnimation()` instead of `setAnimation()` on `ll_mainLayout`, if you want it to start immediately.

Comment: :- tried you answer .. but it doesn't work .... i cannot see the updated text view yet...

Comment: Have you tried setting the AnimationListener *before* you call `startAnimation()`?